# Struts issue in execution in tomcat server

Tags: java, struts2

mentioned is my codes. i need to run this in my tomcat7.0 without using IDE . my application is not getting started. what should i change and where should i keep my files in `tomcat/webapps/`.

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"
      metadata-complete="true">

        <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

struts.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
      Configuration 2.0//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <struts>

        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

      <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
      <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
       <action name=""><result>index.jsp</result></acton> 

      <action name="update" class="demo.Updates">
      <result name="success">Success.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="delete" class="demo.Delete">
      <result name="success">Success.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
      </action>

      </package>

    </struts>
```

index.jsp:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script>
       function submitForUpdate() {
          document.forms[0].action='/update';
          document.forms[0].submit();
       }
       function submitForDelete() {
          document.forms[0].action='/delete';
          document.forms[0].submit();
       }
    </script>
    <FORM> 
            Please enter<br> 
            1.all details to perform update operation:<br>
            2.Only bookname to perform delete operation:<br>
            bookname:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="bookname"><BR>
            authorname:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="authorname"><BR>
            isbn:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="isbn"><BR>
            genre:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="genre"><BR>
            price:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="price"><BR>
            language:<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="language"><BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Update" onklick="submitForUpdate()" >
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Delete" onklick="submitForDelete()" >
        </FORM>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Success.jsp:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <title>Inserted Data List</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <b>Request proccessed successfully...</b>
    </body>

    </html>
```

error.jsp:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <title>Inserted Data List</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <b>Unable to process the request...</b>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Updates.java:

```
    package demo;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    public class Updates extends ActionSupport{

        private String bookname;
        private String authorname;
        private String isbn;
        private String genre;
        private String price;
        private String language;

        public String getbookname() {
            return bookname;
        }
        public void setbookname(String bookname) {
            this.bookname = bookname;
        }
        public String getauthorname() {
            return authorname;
        }
        public void setauthorname(String authorname) {
            this.authorname = authorname;
        }
        public String getisbn() {
            return isbn;
        }
        public void setisbn(String isbn) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }   
        public String getgenre() {
            return genre;
        }
        public void setgenre(String genre) {
            this.genre = genre;
        }   
        public String getprice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setprice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }   
        public String getlanguage() {
            return language;
        }
        public void setlanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }   

        public String execute()
        {

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");

        String s = "update users set bookname=?,authorname=?,isbn=?,genre=?,price=?,language=? where bookname=?";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(s);
        ps.setString(1, getbookname());
        ps.setString(2, getauthorname());
        ps.setString(3, getisbn());
        ps.setString(4, getgenre());
        ps.setString(5, getprice());
        ps.setString(6, getlanguage());

        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();

            ps.close();
            con.close();

                }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return SUCCESS;

        }

    }
```

Delete.java:

```
    package demo;

    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    public class Delete extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        HttpServletRequest request;        

        public String execute()
        {            

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con               =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
        PreparedStatement ps=null;

        String k=request.getParameter("bookname");

            ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from users where bookname=(?)");
            ps.setString(1,k);        
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

            ps.close();          
            con.close();

                }
            catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

                return SUCCESS;

        }

        public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            this.request = request;
        }

        public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
            return request;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not include file with name `struts-default.xml`. This is a configuration file that is loaded by default.

Remove this line

```
 <include file="struts-default.xml"/>
```